# Google Sheets Script to Loop through Stocks Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, gmail

I am new to javascript and am trying to write a script that will email me under the below criteria for any row in the range. However, it's not looping through and emailing properly. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
function FairValueNotification() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Brokerage");
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 40;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A3:M40
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 13);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var PFVRatio = row[6];
    var PFVDollar = row[5]; 
    var TShares = row[13];
    var CShares = row[12];
    var BShares = row[13] - row[12];
    var StockName = row[1];
    var StockTicker = row[2];
    var StockPrice = row[9];
    if ((PFVRatio < 1) && (CShares < TShares)) {       // Trigger only if both undervalued and own less than target shares
    var recipient = 'FIRSTLAST@gmail.com';
    var subject = 'STOCK PRICE ALERT: ' + StockName + ' (' + StockTicker + ') - Brokerage';
    var emailbody = 'The following stock is currently undervalued:' + '\n\n' + 'Stock: ' + StockName + '\n' + 'Ticker: ' + StockTicker + '\n' + 'Current Price: $' + StockPrice + '\n' + 'Stock Fair Value: $' + PFVDollar + '\n' + 'Stock Value Ratio: ' + PFVRatio + '\n\n' + 'You should buy ' + BShares.toFixed(2) + ' shares.' + '\n' + 'You currently own ' + CShares + ' shares and have a target of ' + TShares.toFixed(2) + ' shares.';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, emailbody);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors thrown? I would recommend following the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting), specifically setting breakpoints then stepping through line by line to verify your values are being retrieved as you want.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't throw errors. I finally got an email to send by removing one of the criteria from the if statement, however, it didn't pull in any of the data from the variables into the email. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you're suffering from an off-by-one error? Your `row` variable is a zero-indexed array (that is, to access the first element in the array you would write `row[0]`).

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!